# Class with a list of class in VB

Tags: vb.net, listobject

I am trying to write a DLL that will accept an custom input with a nested list(of T)

I created 2 classes, a Main Class ClassPolyPoints and the nested Class classEF

I am getting an error when trying to pass the list(of classEF) object into the ClassPolyPoints object.

```
Dim TMP_effPoints As New List(Of classEF)

  For i = 0 to 10
        TMP_effPoints.Add(New classEff(
                 i,
                 i*0.125
                 ))
    Next


Dim tmpClass As New ClassPolyPoints(9.8765, TMP_effPoints)
```

Class that contains the nested list(of classEF)

```
Public Class ClassPolyPoints
Sub New(ByVal x_P0 As Double,
        ByVal x_EffPoints As List(Of classEF))

    _P0 = x_P0

    With _effPoints
        For Each a In x_EffPoints
            .Add(New classEFF(
                 a.ID,
                 a.Eff
                 ))
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Private _effPoints As List(Of classEff)
Public Property effPoints() As List(Of classEff)
    Get
        Return _effPoints
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of classEff))
        _effPoints = value
    End Set
End Property


Private _P0 As Double
Public Property P0() As Double
    Get
        Return _P0
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _P0 = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

The nested class

```
Public Class classEF
Sub New(X_ID As Integer, X_Eff As Double)

    _ID = X_ID
    _Eff = X_Eff

End Sub

Private _ID As Integer
Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _ID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _ID = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Eff As Double
Public Property Eff() As Double
    Get
        Return _Eff
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _Eff = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Comment: you forgot to tell us what the error message is.  not for nothing, but VB has had auto-implemented properties for about 5 years now.  Are you using an older VS?

Comment: Try `Private _effPoints As New List(Of classEff)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop here just assign the list.

```
Public Class ClassPolyPoints
  Sub New(ByVal x_P0 As Double,
    ByVal x_EffPoints As List(Of classEF))
   Me._P0 = x_P0
   Me.effPoints = x_EffPoints
 End Sub
 '''
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you forgotten to create an istance of _effPoints before trying to add to the list new elements of class classEF:

That is in class ClassPolyPoints, you have to change the following declaration:

```
Private _effPoints As List(Of classEff)
```

into this:

```
Private _effPoints As New List(Of classEF)
```